# Define a default functor argument using lambda expression

Tags: c++, lambda, functor, default-arguments

I'm trying to define a default value for an argument which's a functor. But I got this error:

note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument
      'Comp'

Here's the definition of my function:

```
template <typename RAIterator, typename Comp> 
void somefunction(RAIterator beg, RAIterator end, Comp comp=
[](const typename iterator_traits<RAIterator>::value_type& a, 
   const typename iterator_traits<RAIterator>::value_type& b)->bool
   {return b<a?true:false;}){
   //the content of the "somefunction"
}
```

I want to know if I could do it this way and if so, which part I did it wrong. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think you can do template argument deduction from a defaulted parameter. You first need to know the template arguments before you can instantiate the function template, including its default parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot provide a default argument for a template argument without requiring the user to explicitly specify what the type of `Comp` is, which for this use-case would be very inconvenient. You could instead do one of two things. You could provide an overload that passes in a default:

```
template <typename RAIterator, typename Comp> 
void somefunction(RAIterator beg, RAIterator end, Comp comp ) { ... }

template <typename RAIterator>
void somefunction(RAIterator beg, RAIterator end) {
    somefunction(beg, end, std::less<typename std::iterator_traits<RAIterator>::value_type>{});
}
```

Or, you can make the type of `comp` a non-deduced context, which would let you add a default argument, but in this case adds likely overhead since we're making it a `std::function`:

```
template <typename Iter>
using value_type_t = typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type;

template <typename Iter>
using Comp = std::function<bool(const value_type_t<Iter>&, const value_type_t<Iter>&)>;

template <typename RAIterator>
void somefunction(RAIterator beg, RAIterator end,
    Comp<RAIterator> cmp = std::less<value_type_t<RAIterator>>{})
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: You can most certainly provide a defaul argument for a function parameter whose type is a template parameter. You just can't do what the OP wants to do.

Comment: @KerrekSB You are correct, that was quite poorly worded on my part. Hopefully the edit is better.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for. So to my understanding, one can not do template argument deduction from a defaulted parameter. But it will be OK if we pass explicitly the template arguments and omit the parameter that has already defaulted value like so: function<someTypeA,someTypeB>(beg, end), right?